# Java Graphics, не работают кнопки

Tags: java, graphics

Пишу в BlueJ программу, которая обрабатывает клики на разные кнопки и выводит в консоль соответствующие этим кнопкам результаты.

Однако, при запуске код реагирует только на последнюю созданную кнопку (origButton), и при нажатии на неё выполняет сразу все ветки условия (в данном случае, печатает разом четыре разные строки.)

Бьюсь уже пару дней над этим, все равно ничего понять не могу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```
import objectdraw.*;

class Button {
    private static Text name;
    private static FramedRect button;
    private static final int SPACE = 5;
    private static final int BLANK = 10;

    public Button (double left, double top, String label, DrawingCanvas canvas) {
        name = new Text(label, 0, 0, canvas);
        button = new FramedRect(left, top, name.getWidth()+2*SPACE, name.getHeight()+2*SPACE, canvas);
        name.moveTo(left+SPACE, top+SPACE);
    }

    public double getRight() {
        return button.getX() + button.getWidth() + BLANK;
    }

    public boolean contains(Location point) {
        return button.contains(point);
    }
}

public class ImageManipulator extends WindowController {
    private static final int LEFT = 20;
    private static final int TOP = 20;
    private static Button grayButton, mirrButton, blurButton, origButton;

    public void begin() {
        grayButton = new Button(LEFT, TOP, "Gray", canvas);
        mirrButton = new Button(grayButton.getRight(), TOP, "Mirror", canvas);
        blurButton = new Button(mirrButton.getRight(), TOP, "Blur", canvas);
        origButton = new Button(blurButton.getRight(), TOP, "Original", canvas);
    }

    public void onMouseClick(Location point) {

        if (grayButton.contains(point)) {
            System.out.println("gray");
        }

        if (mirrButton.contains(point)) {
            System.out.println("mirr");
        } 

        if (blurButton.contains(point)) {
            System.out.println("blur");
        }

        if (origButton.contains(point)) {
            System.out.println("orig");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто была допущена очевидная ошибка.

В конструкторе кнопки атрибуты статические прописал, вот они и переписывались раз за разом.

```
private Text name;
private FramedRect button;
```

Таким образом всё работает.